# Getting meta tags from a page source using Selenium Python

Tags: python, firefox, xpath, selenium

I'm trying to fetch the data from the URL https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en and fetch the below data

```
   <meta content="3.99" itemprop="price">
```

I used the following code implemented in Python to fetch but it failed.

```
    browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
    browser.get(sampleURL) # Load page
    assert "Google Play" in browser.title
    priceValue = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@itemprop='price']")#
    print priceValue.text
```

But it says it can't find the xpath of value price. Any idea why?

**EDIT**

```
priceValue = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//meta[@itemprop='price']")
print priceValue.text
```

I get empty string

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I look at the page source, for example in Chrome `view-source:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en`. I also don't find a `<div>` element with attribute `@itemprop` and value `price`.

So your XPath is completely wrong.  Also `browser.find_element_by_xpath()` returns an element and you want to extract the attribute value of `@content`. You should then use next:

```
priceValue = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//meta[@itemprop='price']")
print priceValue.get_attribute("content")
```

Comment: Using firefox I get the following error with your suggestion:   The given selector //meta[@itemprop=\'price\']/@content is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:\nInvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression "//meta[@itemprop=\'price\']/@content" is: [object XrayWrapper [object Attr]]. It should be an element.'

Comment: Well the XPath to the value `3.99` would be `//meta[@itemprop='price']/@content`. If you need to get the element returned and not the value, you can use `//meta[@itemprop='price']`. That would return the `<meta>` element

Comment: @SiddharthanAsokan you do not need to do `print priceValue.text`, but you want the attribute value or not? You then need to do `print priceValue.get_attribute("content")`. See my corrected answer

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution works fine.

```
priceValue = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@itemprop='price']")
print(priceValue.text)
```